# Kubuntu 22.10 Konsole shortcut CTRL+INS not working, get "5~"

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, konsole

I'm using Kubuntu 22.10, and when using Konsole, if I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> shortcut, the selected text isn't copied, I get a `5~`. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> is working (i.e. pasting works). I've already checked:

1. KDE configuration has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> as a shortcut for copy
2. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> to copy works in Kate

How to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> work as the copy shortcut in Konsole? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm dumb (or the Konsole default config is). By default, Konsole defines the copy shortcut as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which overwrites the global KDE one. Manually changing the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> fixes the problem (go to `Settings` -> `Configure Keyboard Shortcuts` for that).